# firefox html input as null

Tags: javascript, java, html, struts

I have a problem with an html input text field. When using Google Chrome and IE, everything works fine. The field is set on the form and the associated Struts action sees the value.

However, when using Firefox, my cardHolderName attribute is null on the form.

Does anyone have a clue? What is wrong with this?

**My html code:**

```
    <td><fmt:message key="hpciIvr.cardholder.name" /></td>
    <td><html:text style="width:250px" styleClass="field" styleId="cardHolderName" 
         property="cardHolderName" tabindex="10" maxlength="50" size="50"/><br>
    </td>
```

**Using Chrome :**

[image]

**Value is set in form:**

[image]

**Using Firefox:**

[image]

**Value is not set on the form:**

[image]

Comment: don't you need a "name" parameter for html:text? What's the result when you set the form name in there?

Comment: The other fields don't have a "name" and work perfectly with property and styleId

Comment: It's better to include the rendered HTML. Unrelated, but I hope the amount is actually retrieved server-side and not just passed in with the form.